# How do you combine the error of a device with the standard deviation of the readings from it?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, accuracy

I have recorded 3 readings of pressure at a set flow rate for about 8 different flow rates. I know the accuracy of my manometer, and can calculate stddev from the 3 points for each. How do you combine these to give the total error? For the sake of error bars and such.

Comment: Could you explain what you conceive the "total error" to be?  I ask because your data already incorporate all sources of error (almost by definition, for otherwise they would not be raw data), so what more are you looking for?

Comment: For example I'm using a manometer with +-4 Pa accuracy. Say for a flow rate of 10 L/min, I record pressures of 45 Pa, 48 Pa,.and 43 Pa. I can then get stddev for those 3 values. But when I plot the mean pressure against flow rate, I wonder what the error bars should be defined with. Is the +- 4 Pa not something that I need to add in on top of the std dev?

Comment: It's already incorporated in the observations you have made.

Comment: I'm a bit confused at how that works I guess. What about if I use those values in calculations though? Isn't there an error propagation that needs to be accounted for? For example, if I subtract one reading from the other, then my error becomes `sqrt( (4 Pa)^2 + (4 Pa)^2 ) = 5.657 Pa` right? So then the errors become more pronounced, and my intuition tells me that I need to account for that when plotting the mean values with their corresponding error bars. Do you know of any references that describe this effect?

Comment: See posts on *Analysis of Variance.*

Answer (score -1):

If I am interpreting your scenario correctly, you are using repeated measurements on one event to produce an average that is as close as possible to the true value you are trying to measure.  In other words you are measuring the pressure at time t 3 times.  And you have many of these triplet measurements that comprise your data set.

When you make a measurement with your manometer your accuracy spec says that you can not be more accurate than $\pm$4 Pa.  For example, if you measure 43 Pa, you know that the true value of the measurement is between 39 and 47 Pa.  If you repeat that measurement, you could record 42, 45, and 47 Pa, at time t.  Averaging the three measurements yields an Expected Value ( a mean ) at time t.

Because the Expectation operator is linear the mean would have an accuracy of the same $\pm$4 Pa.  If X = (42,45,47) and E[X] is defined as the Expected Value of X and c is a constant defined as $\pm $4 Pa

then:
E[X $\pm$ c] = E[X] $\pm$ c.

Your standard error is an indication of how varied your observations are and not an indication of how accurate they are.

Consider this. If system A produced measurements 43, 44, and 42 then your accuracy would still be the same: $\pm$ 4 Pa. 
However, if system B produced measurements 42,45,47 system A would vary less than system B, but the accuracy remains constant $\pm$ 4 Pa,. I point this out to assert that the accuracy is a constant and can be treated as such to calculate the Variance of a system.

So in short, if you wanted to combine these errors your would take the Variance of E[X $\pm c$].  Since Variance is invariant with respect to changes in a location parameter. That is, if a constant is added to all values of the variable, the variance is unchanged.

It is in this since that your accuracy is already incorporated in your standard deviation.

Comment: This post appears to make little sense, but maybe because I have a standard regression model in mind as well as a conventional idea of "standard error," I might not be reading it as intended.  Could you at least clarify what the expression "$E[X\pm c]$" could mean?  What is "$c$"? What does it have to do with a measurement error? What is the theoretical justification for any of this analysis? What model have you adopted of the data?

Comment: I am also uncertain as to how that works in this scenario. The variance is not a true measure of error is it? And not something that can be plotted as an error bar.

Comment: @teepee I used the variance assuming that you would make the connection between it and the standard deviation.  std = $\sqrt Var$. Also I may have misinterpreted your question, see my edited version of the answer.  I hope this clarifies what I was thinking.

Comment: @whuber I am not looking at this issue as a modeling issue, but rather a sampling one.  teeppee has made 3 different measurements to represent the same data point and asked how to combine the standard error of this measurement with the accuracy of the physical device.  That is how read the question.  Nonetheless, I clarified my response addressing the questions posed in your comment.

Comment: @teepee I noticed your comment was posted at the same time I posted my clarification to my answer.  Does your comment reflect my edits?